# Return Values Below String Pattern Match in Number Range

Tags: unix, awk, grep

I need to match and return the values below the number range 12-00 in the first line/row (UTC) of the following text file:

```
UTC  06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 
TMP  54 53 52 50 49 48 47 47 47 48 48 48 48 48 47 45 44 43 43 41 40 39 38 37 36
```

So that is, matching `12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 00` in Line 1 and returning `47 47 47 48 48 48 48 48 47 45 44 43 43` from Line 2.

**My Attempt:**

```
cat some.text.file | head -n 3 | grep -A 1 '12.*.00' | tail -n 1
```

**Result:**

```
TMP  54 53 52 50 49 48 47 47 47 48 48 48 48 48 47 45 44 43 43 41 40 39 38 37 36
```

**Expected Result:**

```
12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 00
47 47 47 48 48 48 48 48 47 45 44 43 43
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in a single `awk`:

```sh
awk 'NR == 1 {for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) if ($i == "12") start = i; else if ($i == "00") stop = i} {for (i=start; i<=stop; ++i) printf "%s", $i (i < stop ? OFS : ORS)}' file

12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 00
47 47 47 48 48 48 48 48 47 45 44 43 43
```

A more readable version:

```sh
awk 'NR == 1 {
   for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i)
      if ($i == "12")
         start = i
      else if ($i == "00")
         stop = i
}
{
   for (i=start; i<=stop; ++i)
      printf "%s", $i (i < stop ? OFS : ORS)
}' file
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that apparently this code does not work if there are any other 12s that follow after matching 00, like: ```UTC  12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 
TMP  43 43 42 43 44 45 45 46 46 45 43 42 40 39 39 37 36 35 34 34 33 33 32 32 33```

Comment: Correction, this code works fine. I had accidentally typoed something while copy/pasting into the terminal. Thank you I have accepted this answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would use GNU `AWK` for this task as follows, let `file.txt` content be

```
UTC  06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 
TMP  54 53 52 50 49 48 47 47 47 48 48 48 48 48 47 45 44 43 43 41 40 39 38 37 36
```

then

```
awk '/^UTC/{match($0,"12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 00")}{print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' file.txt
```

output

```
12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 00
47 47 47 48 48 48 48 48 47 45 44 43 43
```

Explanation: I use 2 [functions for working with strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) namely `match` which does set `RSTART` and `RLENGTH`, then `substr` to get that part of line or part below it. 1st action is limited to lines which starts with `UTC`, 2nd is applied to all lines.

Disclaimer: This solution assumes that string which have to be matched is known beforehand

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 1):

In general for problems like this where you want to output a set of fields based on some mapping from the input fields I find it best to create an array that maps the output field numbers to the input field numbers (`out2in[]` below) and then iterate through that array:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR == 1 {
    for (inFldNr=2; $inFldNr!=0; inFldNr++) {
        if ( $inFldNr >= 12 ) {
            out2in[++numOutFlds] = inFldNr
        }
    }
    out2in[++numOutFlds] = inFldNr
}
{
    for (outFldNr=1; outFldNr<=numOutFlds; outFldNr++) {
        inFldNr = out2in[outFldNr]
        printf "%s%s", $inFldNr, (outFldNr<numOutFlds ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 00
47 47 47 48 48 48 48 48 47 45 44 43 43
```

The above assumes there will always be a terminating field number `00` in the first line of input, if that's not the case just tweak the logic to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/\s*$//;N;:a;/^12/!s/^.(.*\n)./\1/;ta;/00\n/!s/.(\n.*)./\1/;ta' file
```

Turn on extended regexp `-E`.

Trim the end of the first line of spaces.

Append the the next line.

If the beginning of the first line is not `12`, remove a character from the start of both lines.

If the end of the first line is not `00`, remove a character from end of both lines.

Print the result.